# Reading Http WebResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I get response from an api when i use it to send the sms using http request now i get some reponse when i send the sms . I need to parse "MessageID" from the reponse .

I am using following code to read the response

```
   HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();



        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        StreamReader loResponseStream = new
          StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

        string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

What i recieve in string Response is following

```
<rsp stat=\"ok\">\n<success msg=\"accepted\" transactionid=\"fe417b1b3dd5f68cc99c5df182fe606a\" messageid=\"332b21a2813900a7b81af1635aa1a8d5\"/>\n</rsp>
```

How can parse value of transactionid and message id from this response . Please let me know . Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML:

```
  var successElement = XElement.Parse(response).Element("success");

  var transactionId = successElement.Attribute("transactionid").Value;
  var messageId = successElement.Attribute("messageid").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks it work but can you explain it a bit . and secondly when i was trying like follow it was not working 
         xmlDocument.LoadXml(loResponseStream.ReadToEnd());
      // string value = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("messageid").ToString();
  
 i was able to parse the xml by using INNERXML but not element tag

LoadXml(xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("rsp").InnerXml);  -> it was working

Comment: Well, LINQ to XML is new toy from .NET 3.5 which supports you easily to query data from Xml. You can start in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx. Otherwise, XmlDocument is an old kid which from .NET 1.1.